# How to find total of multiple rows by using angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to find total but it shows 0. I am trying on localhost xamp server.

```
<div data-ng-app="myapp" data-ng-controller="CartForm">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
      <td>{{ x.price }}</td>
      <td><input type="number" ng:model="x.qty" /></td>
      <td>{{ x.qty * x.price | currency: "Rs " }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>{{ total() }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56931296/11572405 answer worked for you then kindly, accept this answer by clicking Tick and also Up Arrow button in front of my answer...Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Syntax Conventions for ng-model is not fine but it will work.

Use **ng-model = "x.qty"**

***But, to get Over-All total, you have to write total() function in JS file.***

***Update 1:***

**HTML File:**

```
<body>  
    <div data-ng-app = "myapp" data-ng-controller = "CartForm">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat = "x in names">
                <td>{{ x.price }}</td>
                <td><input type = "number" ng-model = "x.qty" /></td>
                <td>{{ x.qty * x.price | currency: "Rs " }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total:</td>
                <td>{{ total() }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Angular JS File:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller("CartForm", function ($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {price:2000, qty:3},
        {price:7000, qty:6},
        {price:3000, qty:5}
        ];

    // Function for performing total of all.
    $scope.total = function() {
        var total = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.names.length; i++){
            var name = $scope.names[i];
            total = total + (name.price * name.qty);
    }
    return total;
    };
});
```

Comment: @Iram Haware If this answer worked for you then kindly, accept this answer by clicking Tick and also Up Arrow button in front of my answer...Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Try Someting like this.

```
$scope.getTotal = function(){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.cart.products.length; i++){
        var product = $scope.cart.products[i];
        total += (product.price * product.quantity);
    }
    return total;
}
```